# equivalence of two (convexity) notions

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:S^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a positive, smooth function on the unit sphere. Let $\nabla, g$ be in order the standard metric of $S^n$ and its Levi-Civita connection. Are the two following requirements equivalent?

1-The matrix $[a_{ij}]_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ with entries $$a_{ij}:=\nabla_i\nabla_jf+g_{ij}f~\mbox{is positive-definit}.$$

2-For any great circle on $S^n$ with $\theta$ as it the arc-lenght,
$$f+f_{\theta\theta}>0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix a point $x\in S^n$, define the bilinear form $a(X,Y)=\nabla_X \nabla_Yf+g(X,Y)f$ on $T_x S^n$. $a$ has matrix representation $[a_{ij}]$, so your first condition is equivalent to this bilinear form being positive definite. Meanwhile for the great circle passing through $x$ with unit tangent vector $X$, $f+f_{\theta \theta}=a(X,X)$, so your second condition is equivalent to $a(X,X)>0$ for all $X$. Now the equivalence of the 2 conditions follows from the definition that a symmetric bilinear form $a$ is positive definite when $a(X,X)>0$ for all X.